# Using wildcard characters while running system command in Perl Script

Tags: perl, command, system, wildcard

How can we use wildcard characters while running system command in Perl Script.
For example using *.src to edit a file with sed  - something like :

```
system("sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g'  $baseDirPath/*.src");
```

It gives an error: `sed: can't read /home/test/*.src: Not a Directory`

Here,  $baseDirPath is initialized to /home/test

Comment: The line you show should just work.

Comment: Do you get some error when you try that or is there some other problem? Note that single quotes often are a better idea if your script has a bunch of special characters as double quotes mean the string gets interpolated by perl before being passed on.

Comment: @DeVadder edited the question to include relevant details.

Comment: @AnuragSaran That output is consistent with the perl working as expected. Are you sure there actually are those files? Maybe you meant to use `~/test/*.src` (a test folder in your home instead of the home folder of some user called test)? Quite obviously however, the path and wildcard character did get to the sed command as the error message shows. So if anything, you have a problem with sed here, not Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to chomp the variable `$baseDirPath` before using it, As the line you have written should just work.

Comment: It would be great if you could add a little detail/explanation